# 404 вместо обработки правила htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, сервер

Написал в htaccess такое:

```
RewriteRule ^image/([0-9]+)\.([^/]+)$ image.php?id=$1&end=$2 [L]
```

Что, собственно заменяет `site.ru/image.php?id=40&end=jpg` на `site.ru/image/40.jpg`. На локалке все работает, а вот на хостинге выдает 404 Not Found. Подозреваю, что там как-то иначе настроено, что он ищет реальную картинку.. Помогите, плиз, решить проблему.

Comment: А это всё, что прописано в htaccess?

Comment: @Deonis Нет, там еще правила есть, которые работают

Comment: @inferus-vv, только обратил внимание, что у вас получается как бы "аргумент в аргументе". Если утрированно, то что-то в этом роде:

    site.ru/index.php?page.php?somthing=100500

Я не далеко не асс в mod_rewrite, но думаю, что проблемы возникают именно из-за этого. И кстати, вот яркий пример того, почему не нужно использовать mod_rewrite в таком виде, т.е. прописывая и ломая голову над десятками правил. Когда отличным вариантом, является одно правило: "**все запросы на морду сайта и парсить с помощью php**", о чем я неоднократно писал на форуме.

Comment: @Deonis ну может быть попробую перелопатить потом. Но я не понял, почему получается

    index.php?image.php?

Как правильно?

Comment: @inferus-vv, дык вы ж сами написали в вопросе ))

> Что, собственно заменяет
> site.ru/?image.php?id=40&end=jpg на
> ...

    site.ru/?something === site.ru/index.php?something

Comment: @Deonis Ааа, так это очепятка просто)

Answer (score 1):

[[@inferus-vv](/users/6278/inferus-vv)](/users/6278/inferus-vv), В связи с последними изменения в вопросе, предположу, что правило должно быть таким:

```
RewriteRule ^image/([^/]*[0-9]+)\.([^/]*)$ image.php?id=$1&end=$2 [L]
```

Проверил у себя - работает. Если же не будет работать у вас, то скорее всего, что какое-то другое правило влияет на правильный ход выполнения.

Answer (score 0):

Могу ошибаться, но поинтересуйтесь у хостера, включен ли **mod_rewrite**

Comment: Дело в том, что другие правила работают..

Comment: Может быть к картинкам запрещено напрямую обращаться - direct link это кажется называется...